# Drawing an ellipse with path arc `A` command

Tags: javascript, svg

I wrote below to make the ellipse using path arc commands. But I am using `a` arc command. I would like to switch to `A` command. As it depends on a relative(assumption is wrong as per comment) position

I tried giving diameter values but it is generating random shape. Please help me change it.

```js
function getEclipsePath(start, end) {
  var rx = (end.x - start.x) * 0.5;
  var ry = (end.y - start.y) * 0.5;
  var d = rx * 2;
  return "M " + start.x + " " + (start.y + ry) + " a " + rx + " " + ry + " 0 1 1 " + d + " 0 a " + rx + " " + ry + " 0 1 1 " + -d + " 0 z";
}
var str = getEclipsePath(100, 100, 70, 50);
var test = document.getElementById('test');

var point;
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  point = {
    x: event.clientX,
    y: event.clientY
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  var target = {
    x: event.clientX,
    y: event.clientY
  }
  if (point) {
    var str = getEclipsePath(point, target);
    document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('d', str);
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
  point = null;
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <path id="test" d="
      M 0 0
      a 20,10 0 1,1 40,0
      a 20,10 0 1,1 -40,0
      " />
</svg>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense, the initial position of the arc via the M is absolute, the a values are relative to that (and then each other).

Comment: @RobertLongson I agree with you. Maybe my assumption is wrong but, my question is about how can I use `A` command here instead of `a`